# Android adjusting layout element positions dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview, android-xml

In the below xml I am using boolean value to set visibility to "leave". If flag is true leave image is visible else not visible. This is handled in java code  but the problem is when  leave becomes invisible a gap is created in its place in the UI. How can I adjust the other elements based on visibility of leave to fill the gap?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/head"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluey">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HOME"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="User Credentials"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!-- <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" /> -->
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/head">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/customers"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/customr2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Customers"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dcr"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/filedcr" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="DCR"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/homeLeave"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/leave"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/leave" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Leave"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_mtp"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/cal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="MTP"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/report"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/dcrlisting" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="DCR Listing"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/EMMemail"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/emm" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/reportView"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/report_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Reports"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/communication"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/communication_new" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Communication"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/settings"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/syncnew" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Sync"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/help_faq"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/help_faq" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Help"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/oyolinks"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/custm" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="OYO"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**java code**

```
if(isLeaveEnabled(this)) {
        syncLeave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        syncLeave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: what is the syncLeave here, guy? which view it refer to?

Comment: INVISIBLE will make your view fill the space even though it is invisible, use GONE to completely remove view from layout